# How to show value from 2 promises in a single line?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, es6-class

I have a class with static methods returning promises. I am able to print in console the values returned by these promises in seperate lines. But I want to print in console *in one line* the weather and currency for a given city (say London).
The output should be like this:

```
 The weather of London is cloudy. The local currency of London is GBP.
```

I am unable to do it with nested promises too. How it should be done?

Here is the code:

```
    class Provider{
            static getWeather(city){
            return Promise.resolve(`The weather of ${city} is cloudy.`);
            }
            static getLocalCurrency(city){
            return Promise.resolve(`The local currency of ${city} is GBP`)
            }
         };

    Provider.getWeather(value).then((value)=> console.log(value));
    Provider.getLocalCurrency("London").then((value)=> console.log(value));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```js
class Provider {
  static getWeather(city) {
    return Promise.resolve(`The weather of ${city} is cloudy.`);
  }
  static getLocalCurrency(city) {
    return Promise.resolve(`The local currency of ${city} is GBP`);
  }
}

Promise.all([
  Provider.getWeather("london"),
  Provider.getLocalCurrency("London")
]).then(([weather, currency]) => {
  console.log(`${weather} ${currency}`);
});
```